# Update selected Options not posted when done dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am probably missing something obvious here. I am totally new to Chosen so plz bear my ignorance.
I am using Chosen with Asp.NET MVC for a select multiple. It works fine when values are selected by user manually. 
However when I use an Ajax call to pre-select some values (that already exist in the option list that I use with Chosen) No selected values are posted.

Here what my code looks like

```
          $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "/Project/GetProjectCrewMemberIds",
            traditional: true,
            //dataType:'json',
            data: { projectId: selectedProject },
            success: function (data) {

                $('ul.chosen-choices').empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {                        

                    $('ul.chosen-choices').append('<li class="search-choice"><span>' + item.text + '</span><a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="' + item.value + '"></a></li>');

                });
               // $("#SelectedCrewMembersId").trigger("chosen:updated");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, exp) {
                alert(exp);
            }
        });
```

the Ajax call works and I get the desired values.

When I use trigger("chosen:updated"); the select list gets empty. When commented I get the values added to the list but not posted.

Can anybody tell me what I missing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution, so hopefully this helps someone else :

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Project/GetProjectCrewMemberIds",
            traditional: true,
            //dataType:'json',
            data: { projectId: selectedProject },
            success: function (data) {
                // $('ul.chosen-choices').empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {


                     $("#SelectedCrewMembersId option[value='" + item.value + "']").prop("selected", true);


                });
                $("#SelectedCrewMembersId").trigger("chosen:updated");

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, exp) {
                alert(exp);
            }
        });
```

It is just about updating the selected values in your '' and call .trigger("chosen:updated")

So instead of updating  the "ul.chosen-choices" element of the chosen , just select the  elements needed of the  and call .trigger("chosen:updated"); will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this.  It helped me a ton today!